# How to hot swap JSF xhtml files using Eclipse and WebLogic 11g without JRebel?

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic11g, redeploy

I don't have JRebel. I hope there are solutions out there without buying JRebel.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the xhtml file in place (as in, in the place from which it is running - often your build area for development environments) and it will update on the next refresh.

We have a maven build that only moves xhtml files from our development project to our development (local to each developer's workstation) deployment area.